# remove {} from OrderedDict

Tags: python, django, ordereddict

My method to create data using taskIdSerializer given in below:

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
        result = super(taskIdSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        result = OrderedDict([(key, result[key]) for key in result if result['date']])
        return result
```

This result return in my function given in below:

```
[
    {
        "description": "asdsa",
        "priority_id": 3,
        "name": "tetst",
        "date": [
            {
                "dates": "20/09/2021 15:14:00",
                "id": 146
            },
            {
                "dates": "20/09/2021 15:14:00",
                "id": 145
            }
        ]
    },
    {}, // this is value add dict when date = []
    {}  // this is value add dict when date = []
]
```

I want remove {} object and ı want to get return data like this:

```
[
        {
            "description": "asdsa",
            "priority_id": 3,
            "name": "tetst",
            "date": [
                {
                    "dates": "20/09/2021 15:14:00",
                    "id": 146
                },
                {
                    "dates": "20/09/2021 15:14:00",
                    "id": 145
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: FYI your result is a list of dictionaries, and the empty one you want to remove is at index 1, see the `pop` builtin https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=pop

Answer (score 1):

What you have doesn't look like an OrderedDict to me. An OD is usually represented as a list of tuple pairs. You are showing a list of dictionaries.

If your list is always going to be two elements long, then you can just say

```
result.pop()
```

which removes the last element from the list.

You could make it a little tighter by saying:

```
if result[-1] == {}:
    result.pop()
```

But, in general, I think you need to go back and have a deeper understanding of what output you are generating.

UPDATE:

I must confess I still don't see how the data you're getting is coming from an OrderedDict, at least not from collections.OrderedDict. But, regardless, you have a list of dictionaries, and you want to get rid of the empty dicts. So, something as simple as:

```
result # from before
pared_result = [d for d in result if d != {}]
```

or some might say the following is more "Pythonic:"

```
pared_result = [d for d in result if not d]
```

If the elements of the list `result` are always dicts, then the two above are equivalent. But if the elements can be other than a dict, the two above will differ.

The above modified answers both use a powerful form called list comprehension. It's a great tool to add to your utility belt. :)

Answer (score -2):

Use the **pop()** function to remove.